# My angular-material text is huge and I can't control it

Tags: angular, angular-material

https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

A tutorial here says I should be able to use something like:

```
`<h1 class="mat-display-1">Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.</h1>`
```

To control how the text looks like. 
It doesn't work.

```
`<mat-toolbar>
 <mat-toolbar-row>
  <h1 class="mat-subheading-1">Some incredibly huge text</h1>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>`
```

The text stays very large no matter which class I use. I can only use CSS style to change the text.
What am I missing in this tutorial?

Comment: Okay, so fat my "solution" looks like this ->    `.mat-toolbar h1 {
        font: 500 14px/32px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .mat-toolbar h2 {
        font: 500 8px/32px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
    }` This is stupid, but it's the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you css, wrap the style in `::ng-deep`

If this is your HTML:

```html
`<mat-toolbar>
 <mat-toolbar-row>
  <h1 class="mat-subheading-1">Some incredibly huge text</h1>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>`
```

Your css should be:

```css
::ng-deep {
  .mat-subheading-1 {
    font-size: 16px
  }
}
```

This is because the styles in angular are scoped by default only to that component. So if you want to access a nested component, you have to use the `::ng-deep` selector

**EDIT:**

Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mat-toolbar-style)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but still nothing changed. I tried with  <section class="mat-typography"> and without it. I'm using angular 8.2

Comment: check the this for a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mat-toolbar-style

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what my problem is...I'm using a theme. So when I inspect my huge <h1> text with developer tools I see: `.mat-toolbar h1,  from .../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css.` And my font gets overriden to this: `font: 500 20px/32px Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;` As soon as I removed the css of the theme and commented out custom colors, along with `@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';` line in my scss -everything worked! :) But obviously it broke other things... Is there any way I can keep my theme and color?

Comment: You can, you'll just have to overwrite the styles. if you modify my answer and put `.mat-toolbar h1 { // your styles here}` that should also work